# Using C++ shared pointer's aliasing constructor with an empty shared pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

std::shared_ptr has an aliasing constructor that allows newly created shared_ptr to share state with an existing shared pointer while pointing to some other object.

I was thinking about abusing this constructor to put pointer to some global object inside shared_ptr:

```
int global = 0;

int main() 
{
    // because we point to global object we do not need to track its lifetime
    // so we use empty shared_ptr<void> as a provider of shared state
    std::shared_ptr<int> p(std::shared_ptr<void>(), &global);
    std::shared_ptr<int> pp = p; 
    return *pp;
}
```

My question is: Is it legal? The code successfully works on major compilers.

Note, that I do not ask if it's a good thing to do. I do understand that there's a canonical way of putting pointers to global objects into shared_ptr using no-op deleter. It is also a bit disturbing if it is legal, because it would be possible to have dereferenceable shared_ptr, weak pointers to which are always expired:

```
    std::shared_ptr<int> p(std::shared_ptr<void>(), &global);
    std::weak_ptr<int> w = p;
    if (p) // p is alive and well 
    {      // and w is not
        *w.lock(); // and here program crashes
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already know, with your current solution, `p` has a `use_count()` of zero, that's why the `weak_ptr` is expired. This seems to be ok, according to the C++ draft N4296:

> **20.8.2.2.1 shared_ptr constructors** [util.smartptr.shared.const]
>   template shared_ptr(const shared_ptr& r, T* p) noexcept;
>   13 Effects: Constructs a shared_ptr instance that stores p and shares ownership with r.
>   14 Postconditions: get() == p && use_count() == r.use_count()
>   15 [ Note: To avoid the possibility of a dangling pointer, the user of this constructor must ensure that p
>   remains valid at least until the ownership group of r is destroyed. — end note ]
>   **16 [ Note: This constructor allows creation of an empty shared_ptr instance with a non-null stored
>   pointer. — end note ]**
>
> **20.8.2.2.2** shared_ptr destructor [util.smartptr.shared.dest]
>   ~shared_ptr();
>   1 Effects:
>   (1.1) — **If *this is empty** or shares ownership with another shared_ptr instance (use_count() > 1),
>   **there are no side effects.**
>   (1.2) — Otherwise, if *this owns an object p and a deleter d, d(p) is called.
>   (1.3) — Otherwise, *this owns a pointer p, and delete p is called

emphasis mine.
You could use the following instead which gives a `shared_ptr` with a `use_count()` of one:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> p(&global, [](int*){});
```

This uses an empty custom deleter.

Comment: I did mention no-op deleter as a solution, and I do understand why weak_ptr is expired. The question was is the presented construction legal.

Comment: @Григорий Шуренков I edited my answer to fully answer the question.

Comment: Well, the correct answer probably should include the section 23.11.2.2.1 shared_­ptr constructors [util.smartptr.shared.const] where it is explicitly mentioned that constuctor 

    template<class Y> shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<Y>& r, element_type* p) noexcept;
    
can be used to create such instances: 

    [ Note: This constructor allows creation of an empty shared_­ptr instance with a non-null stored pointer. — end note ].

Add that to the answer and I will accept it.

Comment: OK, I added it.