# initializing a shared pointer with a static or global object

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

The following code shows initializing a shared object with the address of a global or static object is not right as the global object gets deleted when the shared pointer goes out of scope.

```
class Dog() {
public:
    void bark() {
        cout << "Dog barks" << endl;
    }
};
Dog g_Dog;
void test() {
    shared_ptr<Dog> myDog(&g_Dog);
    myDog->bark();
}
int main() {

    test();

}
```

The above code crashes. My understanding is we should not initialize shared pointers with static or global object and should only do so with objects in the heap. Is that correct ?

I saw following code snippet in boost log tutorial
(https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/log/doc/html/log/tutorial/sinks.html)

```
#include <boost/core/null_deleter.hpp>

// We have to provide an empty deleter to avoid destroying the global stream object
boost::shared_ptr< std::ostream > stream(&std::clog, boost::null_deleter());
sink->locked_backend()->add_stream(stream);
```

Can you guys explain why the code

```
  boost::shared_ptr< std::ostream > stream(&std::clog, boost::null_deleter());
```

does not cause any problem. it looks like std::clog is a a glonal or a static variable. Isn't it ? why doesn't it pose the risk of getting destroyed when the above stream shared pointer goes out of scope.
Please shed some light.
Thanks

Comment: The answer to your question is right there in the code: *"We have to provide an empty deleter to avoid destroying the global stream object"*

Comment: Thanks. When I checked the null_deleter in boost, it's a struct with the operator () implemented as below. template< typename T > void operator() (T*) const BOOST_NOEXCEPT {} . Can you kindly explain why is ok in the above code to initiate an instance of the struct by calling boost::null_deleter() rather tha n just providing the struct itself as boost::null_deleter where it accepts a lambda in the shared pointer initialization

Comment: That's called a _functor_.

Comment: Please don't ask questions or add information in comments, edit your question instead. *null_deleter* is simply a no-op. It doesn't do anything. Thus `std::clog` doesn't get deleted when the shared pointer counter goes to 0.

Comment: why do you want to store a pointer to a global object in a `shared_ptr` in the first place? `shared_ptr` is for sharing ownership, globals arent owned by anybody and are "shared" anyhow

Comment: @user463035818 One scenario I can think of is using two APIs together, one expects a shared_ptr, and the other provides a global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link [null_deleter](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/core/doc/html/core/null_deleter.html): boost::null_deleter function object can be used as a deleter with smart pointers such as unique_ptr or shared_ptr. The deleter doesn't do anything with the pointer provided upon deallocation, which makes it useful when the pointed object is deallocated elsewhere.

In other words, using the null_deleter, the smart pointer will never try to delete the pointed object.

Answer (score 0):

It's legal if you provide a deleter which won't attempt to destroy and free it.

`shared_ptr` takes two arguments (check the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)): the address and a deleter. Deleter argument is optional.

The default deleter (i.e. the deleter used when you don't provide any explicitly) destroys the object and frees the heap, so it obviously won't work for anything not on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. Use a nop-deleter. Just accept the overhead of that spurious control-block.
2. Use the aliasing constructor. `std::weak_ptr`s won't work with it though.
   See "*[Using C++ shared pointer's aliasing constructor with an empty shared pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46012436/using-c-shared-pointers-aliasing-constructor-with-an-empty-shared-pointer)*".